# How to fix a type is defined multiple times build error?

Tags: c#, android, .net-core, maui

Using the packages
https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase
and
https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob

When using the Firebase Analytics plugin and the Admob plugin together I get the following build error

```
Error in obj\Debug\net7.0-android33.0\lp\183\jl\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzef.class:
Type com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzef is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\net7.0-android33.0\lp\183\jl\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzef.class, obj\Debug\net7.0-android33.0\lp\243\jl\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzef.class
Compilation failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Debug\net7.0-android33.0\lp\183\jl\classes.jar
<Removed to reduce wall of text>
Directory 'obj\Debug\net7.0-android33.0\lp\183' is from 'play-services-measurement-sdk-api.aar'.    MinReproApp
```

Looking at the map.cache I can see the duplicates are caused by

> play-services-measurement-base.aar
> play-services-measurement-api.aar

I've tried using different versions of the above plugins to no avail.

Clearing Obj and Bin folders then rebuilding doesn't change the error.

I've tried manually removing the conflicting classes which allows the build to complete but then fails at runtime.

Searching has led me to believe it's caused by different versions of the same file but no advice on how to resolve it.

I'm at a loss as to how to debug and fix this and would really appreciate some advice.

I'm very new to MAUI and dotnet mobile so I apologise if this has an obvious answer.

Github link to minimum if it helps
https://github.com/Noobicle/MauiBuildErrorMin